# Client for WebLogic without using Oracle jars

Tags: java, oracle, jms, weblogic, activemq-classic

Naive attempts at connecting using ActiveMQ client fails. [0]

Reading up on it seems the recommended way is to use client jars that can be obtained from a WebLogic server. [1]

Isn't JMS supposed to be a standard so that I should be able to connect using any standard JMS client?

[0]: When I try to connect using ActiveMQ client it fails with "JMSException: Wire format negotiation timeout: peer did not send his wire format."

[1]: For example https://redstack.wordpress.com/2009/12/21/a-simple-jms-client-for-weblogic-11g/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, JMS is a messaging standard.
The JMS API defines a common set of interfaces which is implemented by each provider (or vendor).
Weblogic, ActiveMQ, RabbitMQ or IBM websphere MQ implement their own classes for jms.

That's why you should use the oracle jars if you're dealing with weblogic.
You can generate those jars from the weblogic server with the jar builder tool

```
cd WL_HOME/server/lib
java -jar wljarbuilder.jar
```

It will give you the wlfullclient.jar.

Comment: OK, so kind of like JDBC where the API is the same but you need different drivers I guess.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: JMS is a standard API but doesn't specify a wire protocol.

This is the reason why I cannot expect to connect from ActiveMQ client to WebLogic server.

Some JMS implementations seem to try to work around this. Here is an example I found from IBMs Integration Bus: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ac66100_.htm